# The rep cap is 200 per day, correct?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I got 11+ upvotes and only 29 rep for an answer but my daily reputation was only at 156. That's 44 short of the daily cap! I'm trying to make 20k before the Boston Dev Days, too!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hit the "Today" button on your Recent Activity page - the default timespan doesn't line up with what the rep system considers a "day".

Comment: After clicking Today, I only have 176 rep. That's still 24 short of the cap.

Comment: Well, that number is correct so far as i can tell... no idea why you're capped. You didn't gain rep from a deleted question or answer, by any chance...?

Comment: I was unaware that deleted question rep stayed and was not counted. I had deleted two posts, both of which had at least one upvote, since it was a duplicate of a previous answer.

Answer (score 7):

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow):

> A maximum of +200 reputation may be gained per day. Accepted answers are immune to this cap (source) as are bounties (source). This immunity applies only to answers accepted and bounties received after reaching the cap.
>   *(A new day starts 0:00 UTC == 7pm EST == 4pm PST == 1am CET).*

Comment: I just hit the cap and it's about 6pm EST so that can't be right if that means all my rep was since 2 hours ago

Answer (score 2):

Sort of.  The days that the rep cap mechanism knows about and the days that the rep history knows about are different.  So it winds up looking like you didn't get all your rep for the day, but you did get it all, for some value of "day" (i.e. some 24-hour window, which I think cuts off at 8:00 PM GMT-5).

Comment: It cuts off at 12pm GMT

Comment: Is that a known bug? I've noticed it sometimes gives me unexpected behaviour. If it's not a known bug, it should be entered here as such. :)

Comment: I believe the SO guys prefer to refer to it as 12pm UTC - as that's the easier, and "fairer" common point.

Comment: 12PM is midday, right? Or is that midnight? It would make more sense if the cut off was at 00:00UTC (midnight)

Comment: Yes, [12 p.m. is noon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock). According to the FAQ entry [quoted in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8298/142445) the day boundry for reputation is indeed 12 a.m., or 00:00, UTC. However, that quote is very old and I can't find a current reference for it.