# The 200 Points-Per-Day Question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, daily-reputation-limit

It might have skipped me while reading the FAQs and the posts "[How does “Reputation” work on Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow/7238#7238)" and [The rep cap is 200 per day, correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/the-rep-cap-is-200-per-day-correct)

Say in SO, I've earned 200 points for the day and it's UTC 2300hr. One of my answers are still getting up-vote which will not go into my piggy bank (immunity cases aside). 1 Hr later at UTC 0000hr (+1D), someone up-voted my answer again, do I then resume getting my 10 rep points?

If that's the case, I should 'pray' or 'hope' that the guys up-vote me at a later time so the rep points won't get garbage-collected, yea?

OK, my question is simple, is what I described above correct? If not, what should it be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct.

You can max out your rep riches for the day on one question/answer that's not a wiki, and every subsequent upvote netting you nothing in terms of rep.

But when that UTC starts over again, you can pick up where the stream left off and continue netting more rep from that same post.

Comment: @Random: Thanks for confirming, my steam has died unfortunately :P

Comment: Might I ask, does anyone know why this limitation exists? Is it strictly for the health of people like me so that users don't over-exhaust themselves? I'm sure there's a healthy limit to spending time on a computer :-P