# Is there any limit for the reputation per day for a Stack Overflow user?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [The rep cap is 200 per day, correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/the-rep-cap-is-200-per-day-correct)
>   [How does “Reputation” work on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow)

Is there any limit for the reputation per day for a Stack Overflow user? If so, how much it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A maximum of +200 reputation may be
> gained per day. Accepted answers are
> immune to this cap ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/)) as are
> bounties ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483019/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow)). This immunity
> applies only to answers accepted and
> bounties received after reaching the
> cap.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow/7238#7238)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can earn up to 200 reputation points per day.