# What is the reputation cap on SO?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [The rep cap is 200 per day, correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/the-rep-cap-is-200-per-day-correct)

I can't find anything yet on this question. What is the reputation cap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) it's 200.

Comment: Doh! I knew I was forgetting something... Thank you!

Comment: 200 for upvotes only, minus downvotes. Accepted answers and bounties are not affected by the cap.

Comment: @RobW: Yes, bounty awards and the +15 from an accepted answer are not included.