# Strangely low reputation

Tags: support, reputation

How is this possible that the user with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883166/uncatchable-chucknorrisexception) question only has that little reputation? I've checked his site and he doesn't have a lot of downvotes or bounties.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Daily reputation caps.

Most of the upvotes on the question probably occurred within 2-3 days, netting a maximum of 600 rep (200 per day).

Also see [The rep cap is 200 per day, correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/the-rep-cap-is-200-per-day-correct) and [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: Ah, that's got to sting. He's a new user too.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - I'd think he'd be happy with the rep :)

Comment: Yes. But also displeased with the fact that he didn't get all of it. On the other hand, it's a good start and a whole bunch of badges to start with too. :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten He has a Yearling badge, so not too new. Comparing what he got from that question with the previous year's exploits, I think he won't be too broken by the rep cap.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it applies to the specific user this question is about, but apart from what's already mentioned in the previous answer and/or question, these could be other reasons why a user's total reputation appears to not correspond to the total reputation points by various votes on all of the user's posts:

- posts for which the "*community wiki*" option is enabled do not generate any reputation points anymore (not for upvotes, not for downvotes).
- a user who downvoted (non-wiki) answers, and which are not deleted (yet), will have lost 1 reputation point for each of those downvotes. But these are not shown, by design, in the user's reputation history.
- for each suggested edit (except meta sites), and up to 500 of them, the user who suggested it earns 2 rep points. So without even 1 question or answer posted ever, a user may have already gained 1.000 points.
- association bonus adds another 100 points with no voting involved.
- when an upvoted answer is deleted, and it was posted long enough ago, the reputation points earned from such answer are not always deducted again (not sure about the exact criteria though). Such delete may have been caused by a delete of the question it was related to.